# ASP.Net C# MVC Issue Mapping Domain Model to ViewModel using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I'm having a little difficulty mapping a domain model to a view model, using AutoMapper.

My controller code is:

```
    //
    // GET: /Objective/Analyst
    public ActionResult Analyst(int id)
    {
        var ovm = new ObjectiveVM();
        ovm.DatePeriod = new DateTime(2013, 8,1);
        var objectives = db.Objectives.Include(o => o.Analyst).Where(x => x.AnalystId == id).ToList();
        ovm.ObList = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, IList<ObjectiveVM>>(objectives);
        return View(ovm);
    }
```

I am getting an error on the `ovm.ObList = Mapper....` (ObList is underlined in red with the error):

`'ObList': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM.ObList' instead`

My Objective Class is:

```
   public class Objective
   {
    public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
    public int AnalystId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Analyst Analyst { get; set; }
   }
```

My ObjectiveVM (view model) is:

```
   public class ObjectiveVM
   {
    public DateTime DatePeriod { get; set; }
    public class ObList
       {
        public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
        public int AnalystId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AnalystName { get; set; }
        public bool Include { get; set; }
       }
   }
```

In my startup/global.asax.cs I have used AutoMapper to map the Objective to the ObjectiveVM:

```
   Mapper.CreateMap<Objective, ObjectiveVM.ObList>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Include, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AnalystName, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => (y.Analyst.AnalystName)));
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Mark

Comment: You have nested your `ObList` class inside your `ObjectiveVM` class... so writing `ovm.ObList` makes no sense because `ObList` is not a property....

Comment: Hi - yes I have - but how do I resolve it?  Do I take out ObList and place it in its own class - and reference it from the ViewModel as public List<ObList> ObList ?  Thanks, Mark

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what you do.

Comment: ok thanks - if I do that, how do I then map Objective to ObjectiveVM/ObList here: Mapper.CreateMap<Objective, ObjectiveVM.ObList>() - as it now says ObList is a property but is used like a type.  Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter `nemesv` has rightly mentioned, the problem is about

```
ovm.ObList = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, IList<ObjectiveVM>>(objectives);
```

ObList is not a member of `ObjectiveVM` so, you should change the `ObjectiveVM` like this:

```
public class ObjectiveVM
{
    public DateTime DatePeriod { get; set; }
    public IList<ObList> obList { get; set; }

    public class ObList
    {
        public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
        public int AnalystId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AnalystName { get; set; }
        public bool Include { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Analyst(int id)
{
    var ovm = new ObjectiveVM { DatePeriod = new DateTime(2013, 8, 1) };
    var objectives = db.Objectives.Include(
                 o => o.Analyst).Where(x => x.AnalystId == id).ToList();

    ovm.obList = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, 
                 IList<ObjectiveVM.ObList>>(objectives);

    return View(ovm);
}
```

Comment: Hi - with that change, the error remains on line `ovm.ObList = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, IList<ObjectiveVM>>(objectives);` - as `'ObList': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM.ObList' instead` - thanks.

Comment: @fixit, Try with `ovm.ObList = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, IList<ObjectiveVM.ObList>>(objectives);`

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion - however, I get: Error 'ObList': cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'Objectives.ViewModels.ObjectiveVM.ObList' instead - which is what you've said above: ovm.ObList = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, IList<ObjectiveVM.ObList>>(objectives);

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for all the suggestions - what I've ended up with is:

Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /Objective/Analyst

    public ActionResult Analyst(int id)
    {
        var ovm = new ObjectiveVM().obList;
        var objectives = db.Objectives.Include(o => o.Analyst).Where(x => x.AnalystId == id).ToList();
        ovm = Mapper.Map<IList<Objective>, IList<ObjectiveVM.ObList>>(objectives);
        var ovm2 = new ObjectiveVM();
        ovm2.obList = ovm;
        ovm2.DatePeriod = new DateTime(2013, 8,1);
        return View(ovm2);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ObjectiveVM
{
    public DateTime DatePeriod { get; set; }
    public IList<ObList> obList { get; set; }
    public class ObList
    {
        public int ObjectiveId { get; set; }
        public int AnalystId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string AnalystName { get; set; }
        public bool Include { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CreateMap:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Objective, ObjectiveVM.ObList>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Include, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AnalystName, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => (y.Analyst.AnalystName)))
            ;
```

If I've mis-understood any advice, and you provided the answer, please post it - and I'll mark it as such.

Thank you,

Mark